# Creating a hierarchical, optgrouped, drop down list using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a drop down select list for a web application.
This list must have optgroups, must have indentation (using `--`), and the group names must be options themselves.  Since optgrouping is a requirement, I need to use one of the [group option helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).  Since everything is in one model, I chose `grouped_options_for_select`.

I have a functional solution but it is messy.  Is there any way I can make this neater?  In particular, for the helper method `grouped_categories`, Is there a better way to create the nested array so that i do not need to call the database so many times?

The View;

```
<%= f.label :category_id %>
<%= f.select :category_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_categories.map{ |group| [group.first.name, group.second.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}]}) %>
```

The Helper;

```
module CategoryHelper
 #building an array of elements (optgroup, members), where optgroup is one category object instance,
 # and members contains all category objects belonging to the optgroup, including the opt group object itself
 def grouped_categories
   @grouped_array = []
   Category.where("parent_id is null").each do |g|
     members = []
     members << g
     Category.where("parent_id = ?", g.id).each do |c|
       indent_subcategory(c)
       members << c
       Category.where("parent_id = ?", c.id).each do |s|
         indent_subsubcategory(s)
         members << s
       end
     end
     group = [g, members]
     @grouped_array << group
   end
   @grouped_array
 end

 def indent_subcategory(cat)
   cat.name = '--' + cat.name
 end

  def indent_subsubcategory(cat)
    cat.name = '----' + cat.name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using `awesome_nested_set` or other choice from the [ActiveRecord Nesting category of Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting) on your model. They have helpers to give you the entire tree with a single query, and some even have view helpers for Rails.